# Should something this be a unit test or something else? Using Laravel 8

Tags: php, laravel, phpunit

I've recently built an app that imports around 4500 rows from Excel into a MongoDB database. I have the import working really well, but now I'm running into the GIGO issue.

The excel spreadsheet has a column called 'program_url', this column is supposed to be an external link. About a thousand of these are malformed or lead to 404s.
I've managed to fix the malformed urls during the import (http:www. typt things), but there are quite a few that just lead to a 404 page, and I wanted to test that.

My question is, is it better to test for an HTTP 200 status while I'm running the import? Or should it be part of a unit/feature/browser test? If the latter.. how would I go about doing that?

In the Dusk test I have the following code as a test..

```
    public function test_program_urls()
    {
        $programs = Program::all()->take(5);

        foreach($programs AS $program) {

            $this->browse(function (Browser $browser) use ($program) {
                $browser->visit($program->program_slug)
                    ->clickLink($program->program_name)
                    ->assertSeeLink($program->program_name);
                 

            });


        }

    }
```

The test/assertions pass, but I don't see a way to check the status of ClickLink (https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/dusk#available-assertions)

I tried to do this as a Database test, but that has even fewer assertions..https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/database-testing#available-assertions

Perhaps I'm answering my own question.. and I should just test during the seeding/import and either fix the Excel sheet everytime I run into an issue, or log all the 404s, for future inspection.

Comment: You can certainly write a test to check whether the DB urls all lead to 404, but you can't call it a unit test because you aren't actually testing your own code. This is more like validation of data which you can also do as a separate process (i.e. by queueing a job after an import is done). I wouldn't recommend writing it as a unit test and I would certainly not recommend using Dusk to check if a request returns 404 given how a simple [http client request](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/http-client#error-handling) can do the same and is much faster

Answer (score 1):

if you need to check response code during unit test you can use assertStatus in your test. for the example:

```
$response = $this->getJson($program_url);

$response->assertStatus(404);
```

Or use Http::get  and check status like this. (you can use this anywhere in the code, not only in the test):

```
$response = Http::get($program_url);
if($response->status()==404) {
........
}
```

Or you can use php function: [get_headers](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.get-headers.php). You can also use this anywhere in your code and it's a bit faster than the previous one:

```
private function pageExists($url) {
    $headers=@get_headers($url);
    return $headers && $headers[0] != 'HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found';
}
```

you can use this method like this:

```
if($this->pageExists($program_url)) {
  .........
}
```